# Shard unassigned after failing to flush in elastic search

Tags: java, memory, elasticsearch

From time to time, after inserting new documents in ElasticSearch v1.1.0,  got noshardavailableactionexception error.
When checking with

```
curl  'localhost:9200/_cat/shards/cvk'
```

I got the answer:  cvk 0 p UNASSIGNED

After restarting elastic with  command:

```
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart
```

everything work fine.

ES running on VPS ubuntu v12,  Index have only 1 shard and replication disabled.

I found "no space left on device" error in my log. But I have enough disc space on machine. I'm uploading in a batch of 1000 documents (each one is about 512 bytes).

How to fix flushing problem? And if it's not possible, how to reassign shard via REST interface (without restarting server)?

df from my vps

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda         20G   13G  6.6G  65% /
udev            237M   12K  237M   1% /dev
tmpfs            50M  216K   49M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            246M     0  246M   0% /run/shm
```

log from vps shown errors

```
[2014-05-03 04:20:20,088][WARN ][index.translog           ] [Molecule Man] [cvk][0] failed to flush shard on translog threshold
org.elasticsearch.index.engine.FlushFailedEngineException: [cvk][0] Flush failed
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.flush(InternalEngine.java:829)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.flush(InternalIndexShard.java:589)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.TranslogService$TranslogBasedFlush$1.run(TranslogService.java:194)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(RandomAccessFile.java:520)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.write(RandomAccessFile.java:550)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.flushBuffer(FSDirectory.java:452)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.flushBuffer(BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.java:71)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.flushBuffer(BufferedIndexOutput.java:113)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.flush(BufferedIndexOutput.java:102)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.flush(BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.java:86)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.writeBytes(BufferedIndexOutput.java:92)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.writeBytes(Store.java:634)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.DataOutput.writeBytes(DataOutput.java:52)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.RAMOutputStream.writeTo(RAMOutputStream.java:65)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.writeBlock(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:970)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.writeBlocks(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:579)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter$FindBlocks.freeze(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:555)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.Builder.freezeTail(Builder.java:214)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.Builder.add(Builder.java:394)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.finishTerm(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:1047)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.flush(FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.java:548)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriter.flush(FreqProxTermsWriter.java:85)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHash.flush(TermsHash.java:116)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverter.flush(DocInverter.java:53)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.flush(DocFieldProcessor.java:81)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.flush(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:465)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.doFlush(DocumentsWriter.java:506)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flushAllThreads(DocumentsWriter.java:616)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommitInternal(IndexWriter.java:2864)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3022)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commit(IndexWriter.java:2989)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.flush(InternalEngine.java:812)
        ... 5 more
[2014-05-03 04:20:20,321][WARN ][index.merge.scheduler    ] [Molecule Man] [cvk][0] failed to merge
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(RandomAccessFile.java:520)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.write(RandomAccessFile.java:550)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.flushBuffer(FSDirectory.java:452)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.RateLimitedFSDirectory$RateLimitedIndexOutput.flushBuffer(RateLimitedFSDirectory.java:102)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.flushBuffer(BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.java:71)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.flushBuffer(BufferedIndexOutput.java:113)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.flush(BufferedIndexOutput.java:102)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.flush(BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.java:86)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.writeBytes(BufferedIndexOutput.java:92)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.writeBytes(Store.java:634)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.DataOutput.writeBytes(DataOutput.java:52)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.RAMOutputStream.writeTo(RAMOutputStream.java:65)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.writeBlock(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:980)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.writeBlocks(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:767)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter$FindBlocks.freeze(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:555)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.Builder.freezeTail(Builder.java:214)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.Builder.add(Builder.java:394)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.finishTerm(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:1047)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.BloomFilterPostingsFormat$WrappedTermsConsumer.finishTerm(BloomFilterPostingsFormat.java:439)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.TermsConsumer.merge(TermsConsumer.java:112)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.FieldsConsumer.merge(FieldsConsumer.java:72)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:383)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:106)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4119)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3716)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.merge(TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.java:122)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.scheduler.SerialMergeSchedulerProvider$CustomSerialMergeScheduler.merge(SerialMergeSchedulerProvider.java:89)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.EnableMergeScheduler.merge(EnableMergeScheduler.java:71)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1936)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1930)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.Merges.maybeMerge(Merges.java:47)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.maybeMerge(InternalEngine.java:926)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard$EngineMerger$1.run(InternalIndexShard.java:966)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2014-05-03 04:20:20,382][WARN ][index.engine.internal    ] [Molecule Man] [cvk][0] failed engine
org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.scheduler.SerialMergeSchedulerProvider$CustomSerialMergeScheduler.merge(SerialMergeSchedulerProvider.java:92)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.EnableMergeScheduler.merge(EnableMergeScheduler.java:71)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1936)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1930)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.Merges.maybeMerge(Merges.java:47)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.maybeMerge(InternalEngine.java:926)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard$EngineMerger$1.run(InternalIndexShard.java:966)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(RandomAccessFile.java:520)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.write(RandomAccessFile.java:550)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.flushBuffer(FSDirectory.java:452)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.RateLimitedFSDirectory$RateLimitedIndexOutput.flushBuffer(RateLimitedFSDirectory.java:102)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.flushBuffer(BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.java:71)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.flushBuffer(BufferedIndexOutput.java:113)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.flush(BufferedIndexOutput.java:102)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.flush(BufferedChecksumIndexOutput.java:86)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexOutput.writeBytes(BufferedIndexOutput.java:92)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.writeBytes(Store.java:634)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.DataOutput.writeBytes(DataOutput.java:52)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.RAMOutputStream.writeTo(RAMOutputStream.java:65)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.writeBlock(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:980)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.writeBlocks(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:767)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter$FindBlocks.freeze(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:555)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.Builder.freezeTail(Builder.java:214)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.Builder.add(Builder.java:394)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.finishTerm(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:1047)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.BloomFilterPostingsFormat$WrappedTermsConsumer.finishTerm(BloomFilterPostingsFormat.java:439)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.TermsConsumer.merge(TermsConsumer.java:112)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.FieldsConsumer.merge(FieldsConsumer.java:72)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:383)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:106)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4119)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3716)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.merge(TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.java:122)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.scheduler.SerialMergeSchedulerProvider$CustomSerialMergeScheduler.merge(SerialMergeSchedulerProvider.java:89)
        ... 9 more
[2014-05-03 04:20:20,490][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [Molecule Man] [cvk][0] failed to execute bulk item (index) index {[cvk][public][22017747], source[{"public":"22017747","name":"Private community | VK","desc":"\"\"","vol":0,"priv":null,"org":null,"phone":null,"email":null,"url":"5ghj6","wall":1,"post":null,"like":null,"share":null}]}
org.elasticsearch.index.engine.IndexFailedEngineException: [cvk][0] Index failed for [public#22017747]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.index(InternalEngine.java:483)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.index(InternalIndexShard.java:396)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:401)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:157)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:556)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:426)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is closed
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:645)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:659)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1525)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.innerIndex(InternalEngine.java:532)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.index(InternalEngine.java:470)
        ... 8 more
[2014-05-03 04:20:20,493][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [Molecule Man] [cvk][0], node[Sk1Eoi84TDW9anq_zQsNJg], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkShardRequest@61204bff]
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.applyVersion(TransportShardBulkAction.java:617)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:556)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:426)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2014-05-03 04:20:20,534][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Molecule Man] [cvk][0] sending failed shard for [cvk][0], node[Sk1Eoi84TDW9anq_zQsNJg], [P], s[STARTED], indexUUID [m0nqEEqXQu-rHc5ipn4ZPA], reason [engine failure, message [MergeException[java.io.IOException: No space left on device]; nested: IOException[No space left on device]; ]]
[2014-05-03 04:20:20,534][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Molecule Man] [cvk][0] received shard failed for [cvk][0], node[Sk1Eoi84TDW9anq_zQsNJg], [P], s[STARTED], indexUUID [m0nqEEqXQu-rHc5ipn4ZPA], reason [engine failure, message [MergeException[java.io.IOException: No space left on device]; nested: IOException[No space left on device]; ]]
```

Node info

```
indices: {
  docs: {
    count: 4439439
    deleted: 0
  }
  store: {
    size_in_bytes: 643890465
    throttle_time_in_millis: 0
  }
  indexing: {
    index_total: 2214686
    index_time_in_millis: 1679906
    index_current: 1
    delete_total: 0
    delete_time_in_millis: 0
    delete_current: 0
  }
  get: {
    total: 0
    time_in_millis: 0
    exists_total: 0
    exists_time_in_millis: 0
    missing_total: 0
    missing_time_in_millis: 0
    current: 0
  }
  search: {
    open_contexts: 0
    query_total: 0
    query_time_in_millis: 0
    query_current: 0
    fetch_total: 0
    fetch_time_in_millis: 0
    fetch_current: 0
  }
  merges: {
    current: 0
    current_docs: 0
    current_size_in_bytes: 0
    total: 23
    total_time_in_millis: 1081333
    total_docs: 15716810
    total_size_in_bytes: 5938832547
  }
  refresh: {
    total: 8
    total_time_in_millis: 0
  }
  flush: {
    total: 202
    total_time_in_millis: 677609
  }
  warmer: {
    current: 0
    total: 2
    total_time_in_millis: 15
  }
  filter_cache: {
    memory_size_in_bytes: 0
    evictions: 0
  }
  id_cache: {
    memory_size_in_bytes: 0
  }
  fielddata: {
    memory_size_in_bytes: 0
    evictions: 0
  }
  percolate: {
    total: 0
    time_in_millis: 0
    current: 0
    memory_size_in_bytes: -1
    memory_size: -1b
    queries: 0
  }
  completion: {
    size_in_bytes: 0
  }
  segments: {
    count: 18
    memory_in_bytes: 38866707
  }
  translog: {
    operations: 0
    size_in_bytes: 0
  }
}
os: {
  timestamp: 1399114654034
  uptime_in_millis: 701756
  load_average: [
    0
    0.01
    0.05
  ]
  cpu: {
    sys: 0
    user: 0
    idle: 99
    usage: 0
    stolen: 0
  }
  mem: {
    free_in_bytes: 34357248
    used_in_bytes: 480374784
    free_percent: 33
    used_percent: 66
    actual_free_in_bytes: 172974080
    actual_used_in_bytes: 341757952
  }
  swap: {
    used_in_bytes: 0
    free_in_bytes: 0
  }
}
process: {
  timestamp: 1399114654035
  open_file_descriptors: 103
  cpu: {
    percent: 0
    sys_in_millis: 118480
    user_in_millis: 2057680
    total_in_millis: 2176160
  }
  mem: {
    resident_in_bytes: 263897088
    share_in_bytes: 6635520
    total_virtual_in_bytes: 1609924608
  }
}
jvm: {
  timestamp: 1399114654035
  uptime_in_millis: 43582377
  mem: {
    heap_used_in_bytes: 80238424
    heap_used_percent: 52
    heap_committed_in_bytes: 152043520
    heap_max_in_bytes: 152043520
    non_heap_used_in_bytes: 42873536
    non_heap_committed_in_bytes: 66764800
    pools: {
      young: {
        used_in_bytes: 15877936
        max_in_bytes: 41943040
        peak_used_in_bytes: 41943040
        peak_max_in_bytes: 41943040
      }
      survivor: {
        used_in_bytes: 1463048
        max_in_bytes: 5242880
        peak_used_in_bytes: 5242880
        peak_max_in_bytes: 5242880
      }
      old: {
        used_in_bytes: 62897440
        max_in_bytes: 104857600
        peak_used_in_bytes: 104857600
        peak_max_in_bytes: 104857600
      }
    }
  }
  threads: {
    count: 36
    peak_count: 40
  }
  gc: {
    collectors: {
      young: {
        collection_count: 7359
        collection_time_in_millis: 116960
      }
      old: {
        collection_count: 2693
        collection_time_in_millis: 131864
      }
    }
  }
  buffer_pools: {
    direct: {
      count: 16
      used_in_bytes: 2694367
      total_capacity_in_bytes: 2694367
    }
    mapped: {
      count: 83
      used_in_bytes: 635281868
      total_capacity_in_bytes: 635281868
    }
  }
}
thread_pool: {
  generic: {
    threads: 2
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 6
    completed: 9045
  }
  index: {
    threads: 0
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 0
    completed: 0
  }
  get: {
    threads: 0
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 0
    completed: 0
  }
  snapshot: {
    threads: 1
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 1
    completed: 442
  }
  merge: {
    threads: 1
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 1
    completed: 1297
  }
  suggest: {
    threads: 0
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 0
    completed: 0
  }
  bulk: {
    threads: 1
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 1
    completed: 2213
  }
  optimize: {
    threads: 0
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 0
    completed: 0
  }
  warmer: {
    threads: 1
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 1
    completed: 262
  }
  flush: {
    threads: 1
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 1
    completed: 205
  }
  search: {
    threads: 0
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 0
    completed: 0
  }
  percolate: {
    threads: 0
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 0
    completed: 0
  }
  management: {
    threads: 5
    queue: 0
    active: 1
    rejected: 0
    largest: 5
    completed: 7511
  }
  refresh: {
    threads: 0
    queue: 0
    active: 0
    rejected: 0
    largest: 0
    completed: 0
  }
}
network: {
  tcp: {
    active_opens: 366578
    passive_opens: 32901
    curr_estab: 34
    in_segs: 450996588
    out_segs: 379209662
    retrans_segs: 35059
    estab_resets: 2230
    attempt_fails: 1298
    in_errs: 62
    out_rsts: 6939
  }
}
fs: {
  timestamp: 1399114654035
  total: {
    total_in_bytes: 21003628544
    free_in_bytes: 8092241920
    available_in_bytes: 7018500096
    disk_reads: 4208794
    disk_writes: 5227010
    disk_io_op: 9435804
    disk_read_size_in_bytes: 285034193920
    disk_write_size_in_bytes: 518983745536
    disk_io_size_in_bytes: 804017939456
  }
  data: [
    {
      path: /var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0
      mount: /
      dev: /dev/vda
      total_in_bytes: 21003628544
      free_in_bytes: 8092241920
      available_in_bytes: 7018500096
      disk_reads: 4208794
      disk_writes: 5227010
      disk_io_op: 9435804
      disk_read_size_in_bytes: 285034193920
      disk_write_size_in_bytes: 518983745536
      disk_io_size_in_bytes: 804017939456
    }
  ]
}
transport: {
  server_open: 13
  rx_count: 0
  rx_size_in_bytes: 0
  tx_count: 0
  tx_size_in_bytes: 0
}
http: {
  current_open: 6
  total_opened: 2431
}
fielddata_breaker: {
  maximum_size_in_bytes: 121634816
  maximum_size: 116mb
  estimated_size_in_bytes: 0
  estimated_size: 0b
  overhead: 1.03
}
```

And now shard stay unavailable even after ES restart. Here's the log

```
[2014-05-03 07:10:18,903][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Mys-Tech] recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
[2014-05-03 07:10:18,905][INFO ][node                     ] [Mys-Tech] started
[2014-05-03 07:10:41,334][WARN ][indices.cluster          ] [Mys-Tech] [cvk][0] failed to start shard
org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [cvk][0] failed recovery
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:256)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.engine.FlushNotAllowedEngineException: [cvk][0] already flushing...
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.flush(InternalEngine.java:745)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.performRecoveryFinalization(InternalIndexShard.java:716)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:250)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:197)
        ... 3 more
[2014-05-03 07:10:44,601][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Mys-Tech] [cvk][0] sending failed shard for [cvk][0], node[gknU3JzTRviIpDi4O-rc6A], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [m0nqEEqXQu-rHc5ipn4ZPA], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[cvk][0] failed recovery]; nested: FlushNotAllowedEngineException[[cvk][0] already flushing...]; ]]
[2014-05-03 07:10:44,602][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Mys-Tech] [cvk][0] received shard failed for [cvk][0], node[gknU3JzTRviIpDi4O-rc6A], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [m0nqEEqXQu-rHc5ipn4ZPA], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[cvk][0] failed recovery]; nested: FlushNotAllowedEngineException[[cvk][0] already flushing...]; ]]
```

Comment: Can you run df -h instead and indent the output so we can read it properly?

Comment: You have to check the JVM heap size in your elaticsearch configurations and also where you are storing the data

Comment: VPS has only 526mb of RAM, so I spend about 3 days to setup ES. At first system killed ES (without any errors in log), then I set memory limits too low and ES didn't return any results (ElasticsearchException[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]). But for now it very stable. And there's no common errors in logs. But 'cvk' shard become Unassigned when I add to many documents (more than 1000000) during short period of time (less then 60mins)

Comment: @eliasah , I added node info, and new errors from log. Can you give me any suggestion what can I change in my setup to fix this shard?

Comment: After second restart shard was recovered. But in the log i found 'Unknown mlockall error 0'. Don't know what is it.

Comment: [2014-05-03 07:23:43,781][INFO ][node                     ] [Mys-Tech] closed
[2014-05-03 07:23:45,612][WARN ][common.jna               ] Unknown mlockall error 0
[2014-05-03 07:23:45,760][INFO ][node                     ] [Pixx] version[1.1.0], pid[9951], build[2181e11/2014-03-25T15:59:51Z]
[2014-05-03 07:23:45,760][INFO ][node                     ] [Pixx] initializing ...
[2014-05-03 07:23:45,766][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Pixx] loaded [], sites [head]
[2014-05-03 07:23:49,403][INFO ][node                     ] [Pixx] initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all you appear to be running Elasticsearch with the indexes being created on the root partition:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda         20G   13G  6.6G  65% /
udev            237M   12K  237M   1% /dev
tmpfs            50M  216K   49M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            246M     0  246M   0% /run/shm
```

Generally not the best idea if you can afford to mount another drive.

You failed during a Lucene index segment merge which is generally going to require significant free space. With disk space usage already at 65% on a very small partition of only 20G you can easily run out of space particularly since you are competing with the disk needs of all other processes at the same time. There is more detail here on managing and configuring the Elasticsearch merge policy:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-merge.html

You are probably not going to be able to reliably index and manage 9 GB of data on a 20GB partition that is also the root partition, particularly if you change the data a lot. You can try to set it up to avoid/reduce segment merges which can help with disk space but this still may not work.

Regarding why it takes up as much space as it does this is a function of how you are mapping your data, but in general Elasticsearch defaults to storing a copy of all the data in it's original form, plus all of the indexes for each individual field.

If you really, really need to fit into a 20GB system I'd take a close look at your mappings and see which fields you can either not index or not store -

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem really was in disc space. For unknown reason,  ES take all free disc space.
Here's what happened:

1. I add about 75000 documents via bulk API in index (all successfull).
2. Then do not touching ES at all. And monitoring disc space.
3. During 5 minutes all space was taken by few files in /var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indeces/cvk/0/index/
   The most space took file _3ya.fdt (3gig)
   And right before loosing shard there were files named _3ya_es090_0 with extensions like .tim .pos .doc about 400mb each.
   After loosing shard all those files gone.

So the obvious solution is to add disc memory.

But the new questions:

1. Why ES takes x10 disc space than the size of data being added???
2. Is there a way to know when to stop add new documents in existing shard?
3. will it help if we create several shards instead of one?
4. any other suggestion how to get maximum from current server? Server has 20gig of space. We only need to index about 9gig of data for small research.